# Uncovered footnote appears too early in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, footnotes, overlays

In the following code, I use `\uncover<2->{\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2}}` to uncover `footnote 2` on the 2nd slide, along with `text 2`.

However, `footnote 2` appears on the 1st slide (also on the 2nd slide).

How to fix it? (BWT, I want to keep the `\uncover` semantics; `\only<2->{\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2}}` is not what I want.)

[image: beamer-footnote-overlay]

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Footnote Overlay Tested}
  text 1~\footnotemark[1]

  \uncover<2->{text 2~\footnotemark[2]}

  \footnotetext[1]{footnote 1}
  \uncover<2->{\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnotetext[2]{\uncover<2->{footnote 2}}` hides the text of the footnote but the label is still printed...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit: a much simpler solution is to not worry and just let beamer do the job:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Footnote Overlay Tested}
  text 1\footnote{footnote 1}

  \uncover<2->{text 2~\footnote<2->{footnote 2}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Original answer: A bit hacky, but does the job:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Footnote Overlay Tested}
  text 1~\footnotemark[1]

  \uncover<2->{text 2~\footnotemark[2]}

  \footnotetext[1]{footnote 1}

  \alt<1>{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{~}}{\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So `\alt<1>` replaces `\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2}` on the first slide with `\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{~}` which makes `\thefootnote` do nothing so no number is printed when `\footnotetext` is called and the `{~}` argument prints an unbreakable space rather than any visible text (so only saves enough space for single-line footnotes).

Comment: @DaiBowen Exactly! This is just a hack, so that the space of the second footnote is reserved on the first slide. For multiline footnotes this might still fail, but one could use `\phantom` to fix that.

Comment: Excellent, I'd not seen `\alt` before, it's not quite as elegant as if `\uncover<2->{\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2}}` gave the desired outcome but I can well imagine that's non-trivial to do and this gives all the desired functionality.  I tried using `\footnotetext{\phantom{long caption...}}` but that didn't seem to reserve the correct space on the first slide.

Comment: @DaiBowen Well `\alt` is not really necessary, my first solutions used two `\only` instead, but as the OP wishes not not use `\only` I'm hiding it :)  BTW: I guess we were all thinking much too complicate, see my edit!